# Windows schedule is not launching my ChromeDriver script properly

Tags: python, windows, selenium, scheduled-tasks, selenium-chromedriver

I have set up a scheduled task (win10x64) to log on to a website and do some booking for me using Python, Selenium and ChromeDriver. I used a .bat file to launch the script and all was good until recently. I can't really pinpoint what made this stop working - maybe a Chrome update or maybe the latest big update for Windows 10 (creator).

The script does not work as intended if I launch the script from Windows Task Scheduler. I know the .bat is launched, I know the script is also launched (Python is running the script), and by looking at the ChromeDriver log file, I can see that it is actually being started. The log that is generated when launching with and without the scheduler looks basically the same.

I have tried:

- Updating to Python 2.7.14, Selenium 3.7 and ChromeDriver 2.33
- Writing a basic test (see below)
- Making sure that the users are the same (ownership and privileges)
- Checking the log (as explained above)

It almost looks like Chrome is being launched in headless mode but I can't find any evidence of this in the log files and I have not made any change in that direction. Headless would be fine of course but I remember that I was not able to do the booking I wanted when using phantomJS. I am not sure why. I have also confirmed that the code below is working in the extent that if I try to save the title of the page (`driver.title`) I will get the correct title.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="<path to chromdriver.exe>",
service_args=["--debug", "--log-path=chromedriver_{}.log".format(time.time())])

driver.get('http://www.google.com')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: are you using virtual machine by any chance ?

Comment: no virtual machines!

Comment: is it possible if you can add delay in your batch until `explorer`.exe has been started ?

Comment: @MaheshKaria I don't understand what you mean with that. I can add a sleep XX command for sure, but explorer.exe is already running.

Comment: I don't know how to resolve this, but since I was stonewalled I just gave up and added the stuff to have it run headless and with chrome headless it is now working. Again, still don't know what is happening with the initial problem.

Comment: can you try clear cache once without headless and check

Comment: I had actually done that and another clean up using bleach it just a few days before I posted here.